recharts different Xaxis datakey for tooltip label
I need to have a different value listed as the name when highlighted in the tooltip
which differs from the one defined within the xaxis datakey because they are too long for render
This will only ever set the tooltip title based on the datakey value regardless of what is set in label
export function BarChartComponent({ dataSet, legendType, currentTheme }: GenericChartProps) {
  return (
    <Shimmering isLoading={dataSet === undefined || dataSet?.length === 0}>
      <GenericChartContainer>
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
          <BarChart
            data={dataSet}
            margin={{
              top: 40,
              right: 15,
              bottom: 15,
            }}
          >
            <CartesianGrid />
            <XAxis
              textAnchor="start"
              interval={0}
              dataKey="label"
              tick={<CustomizedAxisTick x={undefined} y={undefined} payload={undefined} />}
            />
            <YAxis />
            <Tooltip
              wrapperStyle={{ zIndex: 1000 }}
              content={<CustomTooltip active={undefined} payload={undefined} label={'name'} />}
              label={'name'} // Set label for tooltip
            />
          
......


import React from 'react';

const CustomizedAxisTick = ({ x, y, payload }) => {
  return (
    <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`}>
      <text x={0} y={0} dy={16} textAnchor="start" fill="#666" transform="rotate(45)">
        {payload.value}
      </text>
    </g>
  );
};

export { CustomizedAxisTick };


import React from 'react';

export const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    return (
      <div
        className="custom-tooltip"
        style={{
          background: '#FFFFFF',
          padding: '10px',
          borderWidth: '1px',
          borderStyle: 'solid',
          borderColor: '#CCCCCC',
          borderRadius: '5px',
        }}
      >
        <p className="label">{`${label}`}</p>
        <div>
          {payload.map(pld => (
            <div style={{ display: 'inline-block', padding: 10 }}>
              <div style={{ color: pld.fill }}>
                {pld.dataKey}
                {': '}
                {pld.value}
              </div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};


enter image description here
here is an example of the elements structure I am working with:
                    "value": [
                        {
                            "Active": 1419,
                            "name": "ABCD",
                            "Inactive": 1640,
                            "label": "abcdefgh"
                        },
                        {
                            "Active": 10850,
                            "name": "ABCD",
                            "Inactive": 4702,
                            "label": "abcdefgh"
                        },


Maybe there is an alternate way but this method seems to work fine for what I need, it allows you to customise the tooltip fully and map individual element props easily without having impact on what is rendered within xaxis, but its a lot more code than what I was initially intending and had to reapply initial css styling
<XAxis textAnchor="start" interval={0} dataKey="label" tick={<CustomizedAxisTick/>} />
<Tooltip wrapperStyle={{ zIndex: 1000 }} content={<CustomTooltip />}/>

import React from 'react';
import { StyledCustomTooltip, StyledTooltipPayload } from './styles';

export type CustomTooltipProps = {
  active?: any;
  payload?: any;
  label?: any;
};

export const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: CustomTooltipProps) => {
  if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    const firstPayload = payload[0]; // Assuming payload is an array of objects
    const name = firstPayload?.payload?.name;

    return (
      <StyledCustomTooltip>
        <div>
          <p>{label}</p>
          {name && <div>Name: {name}</div>}
          {payload.map((pld, index) => (
            <StyledTooltipPayload key={index}>
              <div style={{ color: pld.fill }}>
                {pld.dataKey}: {pld.value}
              </div>
            </StyledTooltipPayload>
          ))}
        </div>
      </StyledCustomTooltip>
    );
  }

  return null;
};

